# Reading keyboard events (Windows 7) with C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, device, keyboard-events, keylogger

I saw examples from keyloggers that are working like that:

```
for (int i = 8; i < 191; i++) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1 == 1) {
            cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

This is working, but it takes events from every keyboard that is connected to the computer (for example the standard-keyboard and a barcode-scanner). 
Is there a possibility to read the events only from a specific keyboard (the barcode-scanner).

I know the function GetRawInputDeviceList(...) that list all the devices that are connected to the computer. This seems like an interesting beginning.

A simple working example would be nice :)

Edit:
I wrote a solution to the problem. It is available under this link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzWPIxqSSyP8fkZiaDI2c3VWNmNqSGd0aDc4TFVpLVYtbWdLdmZjMU9RUVFIMXNtY0FYdEk

It is heavily commented :)
but some of them are in German, sorry :(